# 'function-style cast' : illegal as right side of '.' operator

Tags: c++, enums

I have declared an enum in my `drawview` class:

```
enum current_shape{line,rect,elli};
```

On my main class I have an instance of `drawview` called `m_view`.

I try to set the enum by doing:

```
m_view.current_shape = line;
```

I also tried

```
m_view.current_shape = m_view.line;
```

How can I set this `enum` properly?

Comment: What is the complete error you're getting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An enumeration is a type. Your enumeration type is called `current_shape`. Now you need an object of that type. However, the names should probably be changed so that the object is `current_shape` and the enumeration is `shape`:

```
enum shape { line, rect, elli };
shape current_shape;
```

Now you can set your `current_shape` like so:

```
m_view.current_shape = drawview::line;
```

Answer (score 1):

give `m_view.current_shape` a different name, `current_shape` is reserved as an enum type after the declaration.