# Iterator copy constructor error, illegal as right side '.' operator

Tags: c++, c++11, copy-constructor

after checking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15690249/function-style-cast-illegal-as-right-side-of-operator) answer I still could not seem to solve my issue:

I currently have a `test_iterator` struct, which will wrap different types of iterator tags onto it allowing me to test function using all types of iterators. My problem comes when creating a copy constructor for this iterator. the current struct is defined as

```
template <typename BaseIterator, typename IteratorTag>
struct test_iterator
  : boost::iterator_adaptor<
        test_iterator<BaseIterator, IteratorTag>,
        BaseIterator, boost::use_default, IteratorTag>
{
private:
    typedef boost::iterator_adaptor<
        test_iterator<BaseIterator, IteratorTag>,
        BaseIterator, boost::use_default, IteratorTag>
    base_type;

public:
    test_iterator() : base_type() {}
    test_iterator(BaseIterator base) : base_type(base) {};

    test_iterator(const test_iterator& cpy): 
        base_type(cpy.base_type) {};
};
```

The last constructor(the copy constructor) is giving me trouble, I can't seem to grasp what I am doing wrong. the exact error I receive is

```
error C2274: 'function-style cast' : illegal as right side of '.' operator
```

which is this line:

```
base_type(cpy.base_type) {};
```

Comment: Are you testing the code in your function or the iterators?

Comment: You don't have a constructor that accepts a function object. Are you sure you didn't mean base_type(cpy.base_type()) ?

Comment: Let the compiler define the copy constructor (and the move constructor, and the destructor, and the copy/move assignments) implicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't have a type on the right side of the `.`. You can either use

```
test_iterator(const test_iterator& cpy)
    : base_type(static_cast<base_type const&>(cpy)) {}
```

...or, given that the base type is specified already, you can just use

```
test_iterator(const test_iterator& cpy)
    : base_type(cpy) {}
```

Comment: Note, however, that the two ways you show will have different behaviour in case `base_type` also has a ctor which accepts a `const test_iterator &` (which I can easily imagine in this case).

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```
base_type(cpy.base_type) {};
```

you refer to the `base_type`, which is a typedef, and you want the underlying iterator. You need to call `base()` method provided by iterator_adaptor:

```
base_type(cpy.base()) {};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test_iterator(const test_iterator& cpy): 
    base_type(cpy.base_type) {};
```

Class `test_iterator` has no member `base_type`, but a typedef `base_type` ,so **if** you really want to initialize the base from thin air, it would be

```
test_iterator(const test_iterator& cpy): 
    base_type(base_type()) {};
```

But that'd be rather pointless, because that would yield a `nullptr` equivalent.

I suppose you instead want to achieve is

```
 test_iterator(const test_iterator& cpy): 
        base_type(/*(const base_type&)*/cpy) {};
```

which is legal, because `test_iterator` inherits from `base_type` (I assume that base-type actually has a copy ctor taking a base_type const&); but that downcast is sth the compiler does for you, so you don't need to cast it manually.

---

Btw - I assume that this

```
test_iterator(BaseIterator base) : base_type(base) {};
```

should be

```
test_iterator(const BaseIterator& base) : base_type(base) {};
```

shouldn't it.